# I unified the Android Gradle version, but "mixing version" pops up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

The program will run normally. 
But by removing the error mark, I want to prevent potential danger.

My targetSdkVersion is 26.
So I have unified all Gradle Version to 26.
However, the Android studio warns that 25.2.0 still exists and that it is a mixed version. However, no matter how I look, I did not see 25.2.0.

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
Found versions 26.1.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0

There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version(or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)
```

[image]

---

I could not find 'Gradle Version 25' no matter how I searched. And I could not find "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0" in the warning. Why is this phrase coming out?

(error pop up : implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0')

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword 'abcde'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/aaaa/.AndroidStudio2.3/key.jks')
            storePassword 'aaaaaaa'
        }
    }


    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example.aaaaa.abcde"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'


    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    // Login php Connect
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'




    // Open source plus
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile group: 'com.kakao.sdk', name: 'kakaolink', version: project.KAKAO_SDK_VERSION
    compile project(':airquality-release')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile "com.github.katoro:typekit:1.0.1"  
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

---

I looked at all the other files in the Gradle subfolder, but I could not find the 25 trace. (There are other files besides the attached code below, but I did not attach it because it was about 10 lines of short code.)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// Open source plus
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://devrepo.kakao.com:8088/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Open source plus
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: what is version of your android studio

Comment: Try to update all libraries into latest versions

Comment: Ankesh Roy // My Android Studio version is 3.0. And I combined my project with open source. There is more code from outside than my code.

Comment: hungryhungry//update that to 3.0.1

Comment: sorry :)  I have 3.0.1. (I typed it wrong) Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your build.gradle(Module:project) like below code....

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and make your build.gradle(Module:app) like below code you can add your own useful dependencies and remove my unused dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "talent4assure.com.manageyourrestaurant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I could not paste your code as it is. What is the key part?

Comment: use project graddle completely and user '26.+ '